# Osmf Player quality chooser in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, m3u8, osmf

I'm using the osmf swc to develop a custom player for streaming, I´m using this tutorial:
http://flashphorm.blogspot.pe/2012/09/play-m3u8-http-stream-through-flash.html

Everything works fine but I want to know if it is posible to make a bitrate (quality of the stream) chooser for the streaming?

I have checked all examples in adobe devnet but all of them are using three or more flv files, in my case I will use m3u8

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I  found this awesome libraty to play HLS in as3.

https://github.com/mangui/flashls

It has a plugin that can be integrated with these players:

- Flowplayer 3.2.12 OSMF 2.0 based players (such as SMP and
  GrindPlayer)
- Video.js 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 (adaptation done here
  https://github.com/mangui/video-js-swf)
- MediaElement.js

But also you can integrated it with your own personal custom player

Thanks

Best regards